# Emacs/Auctex: Automatically enabling/disabling LaTeX-Math-mode

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using Emacs in conjunction with AucTeX (running Ubuntu 10.04, if that matters).

Does anyone know if there is a way to automatically enable LaTeX-math-mode (a minor mode of AucTeX) if the point is in any maths environment (i.e. in a `$...$`, a `$$...$$`, `begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, and so on)?

I suppose there is a relatively easy answer, since syntax highlighting uses the same criterion for coloring math stuff, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If [andre-r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166057/andre-r)'s answer doesn't satisfy you, here's some code that sets up `` ` `` to self-insert in text mode and act as a math mode prefix in math mode. `LaTeX-math-mode` must be *off*.

```
(defun LaTeX-maybe-math ()
  "If in math mode, act as a prefix key for `LaTeX-math-keymap'.
Otherwise act as `self-insert-command'."
  (interactive)
  (if (texmathp)
      (let* ((events (let ((overriding-local-map LaTeX-math-keymap))
                       (read-key-sequence "math: ")))
             (binding (lookup-key LaTeX-math-keymap events)))
        (call-interactively binding))
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map "`" 'LaTeX-maybe-math)
```

The following improvements are left as exercises:

- Make it a minor mode.
- Make it more robust towards unexpected input (I've only tested basic operation).
- Show a better error message if the user presses an unbound key sequence.
- Show help if the user presses `C-h` or `f1`.

Comment: I am having an error as: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable LaTeX-mode-map)
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "`" 'LaTeX-maybe-math)`

Answer (score 4):

`LaTeX-math-mode` is *"a special minor mode for entering text with many mathematical symbols."* (For those who don't know how, you press e.g. `A and get \forall.) So I guess it doesn't hurt to leave it on, also if you're not entering maths.

The info page therefore suggests:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
```

IMHO the only downside would be that you  have to press  the prefix twice: `` to get `, at least that works with the standard prefix ` customized in `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix`.